# What is the best unique pointer for use with a custom allocator?

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, unique-ptr, allocator

I am using a custom allocator which needs to know the real type of an object upon deletion. *It should also deallocate the same exact address as was received from the allocate function. This is my first project using any kind of special allocators so I really have no experience or knowledge of best practices. I would like to essentially have the same semantics as a unique pointer. Here an obvious failed attempt to show the problem:

```
template<typename T>
void* allocate(){
    return malloc(sizeof(T)); //I really do something else but its beyond the scope of this example
}

template<typename T>
void deallocate(T * p){
    // T must be real T and not base of T
    free(p); //I really do something else but its beyond the scope of this example
}
std::unique_ptr<Base> pb(new Base);
std::unique_ptr<Derived> pd(new Derived);
std::unique_ptr<Base> pb2(std::move(pd));
//std::unique_ptr<Derived> pd2(std::move(pb)); this should not compile
//pb.swap(pd); this should not compile
pb.swap(pb2);
```

This fails because unique_ptr needs to call my deallocate rather than delete.

What is the best pointer to use in this case?

UPDATE:

adding a stateful costume deleter with type erasure would probably solve my problem. Here is an example with a std::function

```
template<typename T>
using UniquePtr = std::unique_ptr<T,std::function<void(T*)>>;

//using my special unique_ptr
UniquePtr<Base> upb(new (allocate<Derived>()) Derived,[](Base*p){
        if(p!=nullptr){
            auto d = static_cast<Derived*>(p);
            d->~Derived();
            deallocate(d); 
        }
    });
```

I can't think of another way to let the knowledge of the real derived class follow the pointer in the case that it is converted to a base and then moved around. This seems very verbose and error prone though. Is this the best way ?

EDIT 2:
adding a factory function takes care of some of the ugliness and makes this less error prone:

```
template<typename T_Base, typename T_Derived, typename... Ts>
std::unique_ptr<T_Base,std::function<void(T_Base* p)>> MakeUnique(Ts &&... Args){
    return std::unique_ptr<T_Base,std::function<void(T_Base*)>>(
        new (allocate<T_Derived>()) T_Derived(std::forward<Ts>(Args)...),
        [](T_Base*p){
            if(p!=nullptr){
                auto d = static_cast<T_Derived*>(p);
                d->~T_Derived();
                deallocate(d); 
            }
        });
}

//example use
auto mupd = MakeUnique<Base,Derived>();
auto mupdd = MakeUnique<Derived,Derived>();
auto mupb = MakeUnique<Base,Derived>();
auto mupbb = MakeUnique<Base,Base>();
mupbb.swap(mupb);
mupb = std::move(mupd);
//mupb = std::move(mupdd); should give error
```

This is starting to feel usable so it seems I may have solved my own problem. I am still quite greatfull to anyone offering critique or thoughts.

*I was originally unclear about this requirement.

Comment: From the code you've shown, there is absolutely no reason to know the derived type: jut make your base destructor virtual and call it, it will automatically call the derived destructor too. Anything else (calling a specific method on the derived object) is a design stink and should rather be handled in the derived class' destructor.

Comment: @syam I am aware of the need for virtual destructors, however, in this specific case my deallocate function MUST be called with the same type as allocate. It would take a while to get into why so lets just say its a requirement.

Comment: @syam "Make the client classes polymorphic" is usually not a viable quick fix when a custom allocator is already necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for.  But you can get a lot of the functionality of a "dynamic deleter" by using a function pointer as a deleter with `unique_ptr`:

```
std::unique_ptr<Base, void(*)(void*)> p(allocate<Derived>(), deallocate<Derived>);
```

The deleter is just a function.  But at run time you can feed it a pointer to a templated function, templated on your `Derived` type.  It allows the right destructor to be called, even if the destructor isn't virtual.  Though anything else called via this pointer must be virtual, or it will resolve to the `Base` class of course.  Here's a full HelloWorld:

```
#include <memory>
#include <new>
#include <cstdlib>

template<typename T>
T*
allocate()
{
    std::unique_ptr<T, void(*)(void*)> hold(static_cast<T*>(std::malloc(sizeof(T))),
                                                            std::free);
    ::new (hold.get()) T;
    return static_cast<T*>(hold.release());
}

template<typename T>
void
deallocate(void* p)
{
    static_cast<T*>(p)->~T();
    std::free(p);
}

#include <iostream>

struct Base
{
    Base() {std::cout << "Base()\n";}
    Base(const Base&) = delete;
    Base& operator=(const Base&) = delete;
    ~Base() {std::cout << "~Base()\n";}

    virtual void bark() const {std::cout << "Hi Base!\n";}
};

struct Derived
    : public Base
{
    Derived() {std::cout << "Derived()\n";}
    Derived(const Base&) = delete;
    Derived& operator=(const Derived&) = delete;
    ~Derived() {std::cout << "~Derived()\n";}

    void bark() const {std::cout << "Hi Derived!\n";}
};

int
main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<Derived, void(*)(void*)> p(allocate<Derived>(), deallocate<Derived>);
    p->bark();
    std::unique_ptr<Base, void(*)(void*)> p2 = std::move(p);
    p2->bark();
}

Base()
Derived()
Hi Derived!
Hi Derived!
~Derived()
~Base()
```

Comment: Yes of course a simple function pointer is much smaller than a std::function and it fulfills all the requirements.

Comment: I guess I spoke too soon, this breaks as soon as a pointer to Derived and a pointer to Base are not the same address (because of a vtable or multiple inheritance) because static_cast<Derived*>(static_cast<void*>(static_cast<Base*>(p))) is not always equal to p. see http://ideone.com/6Xj0O3

Comment: this http://ideone.com/521Q7V fixes the problem but is less flexable, I think I will use this method but add a factory so that users cannot break it as easily.

Comment: A new version with templated arguments: https://ideone.com/bIBHpt